# Colour <A> tags to anchors when active just (preferably with CSS)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Having a layout like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UuD73/27/

```
<div>
    navi 1<br>
<a href="#anchor1">Anchor 1</a><br/>
<a href="#anchor2">Anchor 2</a><br/>
<a href="#anchor3">Anchor 3</a><br/>
    navi 2<br>
<a href="#anchor1">Anchor 1</a><br/>
<a href="#anchor2">Anchor 2</a><br/>
<a href="#anchor3">Anchor 3</a><br/>
</div>

</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="anchor1" id="anchor1">Here is anchor 1</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="anchor2" id="anchor2">Here is anchor 2</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="anchor3" id="anchor3">Here is anchor 3</a>
```

```
​div{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
a, a:active, a:visited{
    color: green;
}
```

with 2 identical navigation menus, which jump to anchors in the page. Would it be possible to colour the 2 active links when one of them is clicked, preferably using only CSS?

**Edit:** Ive updated the fiddle. I noticed I didnt show the 2 navigation menus

Comment: Please include your code in the post.  Simply using a link to jsFiddle  without posting the code here is against Stackoverflow policy.

Comment: Also, I'm confused about what you're asking. Do you want a different color for visited links, or...? Which *2* active links?

Comment: I agree with Colleen.  Do you mean when you hover over the href or when you click the href it turns to a different color permanently?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code. I've changed the fiddle.

Comment: Ah, let me make a few adjustments...

Comment: What's up with all those `<br>`s? Use CSS for formatting and margins instead.

Comment: All those `<br />` tags are a bit ridiculous.

Comment: I just use them to simulate the space between the anchors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and [updated mattematico's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuD73/26/)

1. The styling for the :active pseudoclass can be seen when clicking
   down on an anchor, but this goes away when released.
2. Simplified mattematico's script to correctly toggle the color using
   addClass/removeClass.
3. Added an .activeLink class to the style sheet.

**Edit**

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuD73/30/)

```
$(function() { 
    // selector for any anchor with an href that begins with '#'.
    var bookmarkSelector = 'a[href^="#"]';
    $(bookmarkSelector).click(function(){ 
        $(bookmarkSelector).removeClass('activeLink'); 
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').addClass('activeLink'); 
    });
});​
```

1. Updated selector so that Click function only applies to bookmark anchors.
2. Added a link to stackoverflow and a js-alert link to ensure the effect didn't fire in those cases.
3. Added a link back to this post.
4. Removed <br/> tags.

Comment: I guess theres no real pure CSS solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if its possible with css only, but with jquery you can do it like this. If it was like this you wanted it?

Your html

```
<div>
<a href="#anchor1">Anchor 1</a><br/>
<a href="#anchor2">Anchor 2</a><br/>
<a href="#anchor3">Anchor 3</a><br/>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="anchor1" id="anchor1">Here is anchor 1</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="anchor2" id="anchor2">Here is anchor 2</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="anchor3" id="anchor3">Here is anchor 3</a>

​
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').css('color', 'green');
       var selector = $(this).attr('href');
        $(selector).css('color', 'black');
    });
});​
```

And your css

```
div{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
a, a:active, a:visited{
    color: green;
}
​
```

Working example [here @ jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuD73/20/)